# Connect to different Oracle database and transfer table through Stored Procedure

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have 2 Oracle databases on different servers:

Oracle 1
Oracle 2

I want to run a stored procedure which will execute in Oracle 1 and do the following:

a) Connect with Oracle 2
b) Create db link in Oracle 2 to connect with Oracle 1 OR use existing one if already created
c) Copy table 1 from Oracle 1 to Oracle 2

I am able to do it using:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK mylink
  CONNECT TO source_user IDENTIFIED BY source_password
  USING source_entry_in_tnsnames';
```

Copy the data:

```
INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM mytable@mylink;
```

I wrote a stored procedure and included these but am not able to connect with Oracle 2. How can we connect to another Oracle database from stored procedure?

Comment: Unless you're using autonomous transactions there should be no problem at all connecting to Oracle 2 using mylink.  Could you please share any error messages?  I don't believe you will need to create your second db link - just use mylink to transfer the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a rights issue. Your Database Link on the target Oracle DB that has the procedure you want call. It must have execute rights for that package / proc.

Also, I have found I must call those target procs with the schema name. Such as schema.package.procedure@dblink(parms). If I did not have the schema on the proc call the package would not compile.

Side Note... If you are calling a procedure over a link that has a refCursor returned it will not work. (at least on Oracle 10 and 11). In those cases I had to return a table.